# Cosa significa "a cantilena" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Non ora, non qui*, di Erri De Luca, ho letto:

> Ho avuto vent’anni e il freddo delle anticamere. Una, la più strana, rammento. Mi presentai tra molti a un provino cinematografico per una piccola presenza in un film. Sapevo che si sarebbe svolto in un campo di prigionia tedesco. Quando toccò a me, mi dissero di avanzare. Ero su un palcoscenico illuminato e in platea sedevano i responsabili. Non riuscivo a vederli per la forte luce che mi copriva. Avanzai col mio passo sghembo **a cantilena**. Si aspettavano un ingresso marziale perché stavano esaminando i ruoli secondari delle guardie del campo. Non potevo saperlo. Risero. Dal buio della sala vennero risa antiche, un rumore già conosciuto. Non me ne andai, non arrossii. Aspettai che finisse, ma stentavo a muovermi. Un gelo mi aveva preso le 
>   gambe, come altre volte la lingua. Rimasi rigido e storto con gli occhi aperti a frugare il buio, il vuoto sulle loro teste, finché uno mi chiese se avevo fatto il servizio militare.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "cantilena" in parecchi dizionari, ma non capisco il senso dell'espressione "a cantilena" in questo brano. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: immagino significhi "con un andamento lento e monotono"

Comment: In effetti è un'espressione strana: anche a me farebbe pensare a qualcosa di ripetitivo e monotono, ma su un palcoscenico si possono fare pochi passi, non abbastanza da instaurare una monotonia. Personalmente mi sento confermato nel fatto che Erri De Luca è un po' sopravvalutato...

Answer (score 2):

Il dizionario Hoepli definisce cantilena in senso figurato :

> ( fig., poet.) Ripetizione di cose, d'immagini sempre uguali: *cantilena  di remi e di cordami (Quasimodo)*

L’uso fatto nel brano si riferisce a questa estensione dell’uso  letterale.

Comment: Quindi, si tratterebbe di una ripetizione di passi sempre uguali? O significa che il passo era ugualmente sghembo in altre situazioni?

Comment: Cantilena si riferisce ad una ripetizione sempre uguale fino alla monotonia. In questo caso l’essere sghembo forse  contribuisce a dare un tono lento e uguale al passo, ma sghembo in sé non ha nessuna relazione con una cantilena.